# Shell Script with sqlplus and special characters on password

Tags: linux, bash, oracle, shell, sqlplus

I have a question that mix Linux / Unix shell-scripting and sqlplus (Oracle) that is driving me crazy. :-)

sqlplus utilize a syntax like this:

```
./sqlplus johnF/mypassword@127.0.0.1:1521/SID
```

And it works fine. However my password is not simple as "mypassword", it utilize "!" and "@" and sometimes even "\". For this example, let's suppose that my password is !p@ssword

If I use the following syntax in sqlplus it works:

```
./sqlplus johnF/'"!p@ssword"'@127.0.0.1:1521/SID
```

That's great. However I wanted to use it in a shell script that get call sqlplus and get many parameters from files (username, password, SID and SQL QUERY), just for example let me use a reduced code.

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS=: read -r line
do

        echo "./sqlplus johnF/$line@127.0.0.1:1521/SID" 
        echo -e 'select 1 from dual;\nexit;' |  ./sqlplus johnF/$line@127.0.0.1:1521/SID

done < $1
```

I have attempted to fix it in many ways, including:

```
echo -e 'select 1 from dual;\nexit;' |  ./sqlplus johnF/'"$line"'@127.0.0.1:1521/SID
echo -e 'select 1 from dual;\nexit;' |  ./sqlplus johnF/'\"$line\"'@127.0.0.1:1521/SID
echo -e 'select 1 from dual;\nexit;' |  ./sqlplus johnF/\'\"$line\"\'@127.0.0.1:1521/SID
```

And many others and all fails, in a few cases the first echo print the output exactly as it should be passed to sqlplus, but it never works, returns login denied (wrong password) or connection issues (maybe the @ being intercepted as wrong target).

How to solve this puzzle?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Operation)? Or perhaps using a heredoc?

Comment: Can you use sqlplus /nolog, and then a connect statement within the sqlplus script. That should remove some of the shell interactions which complicate the issue.

Comment: could you share your `alter user johnF identified by ???` statement?

Comment: There are a number of oracle MOS articles related to special characters associated with database passwords like, https://support.oracle.com/MMOS/faces/ui/km/kmDocumentDisplay.jspx?parent=DOCUMENT&sourceId=820680.1&kmDocId=305981.1. There is guidance on escaping and use of quotation marks.

Comment: Thanks guys, my password was changed correctly. And I know basic of shell escaping, but I'm not able to apply it to send the special password inside shellscript where the data on the middle of it is a variable. I believe that my script reproduce the issue. Any solution?

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Configure the config file `sqlnet.ora`  for an easy connection.

```
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES,ezconnect)
```

Change the password @T!ger to the user "Scott".

```
oracle@esmd:~>
oracle@esmd:~> sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Mon Jan 29 11:05:04 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> alter user "Scott" identified by "@T!ger";

User altered.
```

**Example 1**  Script is test_echo.sh

```
    #!/bin/sh

    username=\"Scott\"
    password=\"@T!ger\"
    ezconnect=10.89.251.205:1521/esmd

    echo username:  $username
    echo password:  $password
    echo ezconnect  $ezconnect

 echo -e 'show user \n  select 1 from dual;\nexit;' |  sqlplus  $username/$password@$ezconnect

oracle@esmd:~> ./test_echo.sh
username: "Scott"
password: "@T!ger"
ezconnect 10.89.251.205:1521/esmd

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Mon Jan 29 11:02:52 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> USER is "Scott"
SQL>
         1
----------
         1

SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
```

**Example 2** Run script test_echo.sh in silent mode sqlplus

```
#!/bin/sh

username=\"Scott\"
password=\"@T!ger\"
ezconnect=10.89.251.205:1521/esmd

echo username:  $username
echo password:  $password
echo ezconnect  $ezconnect
echo -e 'show user \n  select 1 from dual;\nexit;' |  sqlplus -s  $username/$password@$ezconnect

oracle@esmd:~> oracle@esmd:~> ./test_echo.sh
username: "Scott"
password: "@T!ger"
ezconnect 10.89.251.205:1521/esmd
USER is "Scott"

         1
----------
         1
```

**Example 3**  A little bit Another syntax

```
#!/bin/sh

username=\"Scott\"
password=\"@T!ger\"
ezconnect=10.89.251.205:1521/esmd


echo username:  $username
echo password:  $password
echo ezconnect: $ezconnect

testoutput=$(sqlplus -s $username/$password@$ezconnect  << EOF
set pagesize 0 feedback off verify off heading off echo off;
show user
SELECT to_char(sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI')||' Test passed' from dual
exit;
EOF
)

echo $testoutput

oracle@esmd:~> ./test_Upper_case.sh
username: "Scott"
password: "@T!ger"
ezconnect: 10.89.251.205:1521/esmd
USER is "Scott" 29-01-2018 11:55 Test passed
```

Answer (score 1):

i assume you issued this to alter your user's password :

```
alter user johnF identified by "!p@ssword";
```

since

```
alter user johnF identified by !p@ssword;
```

doesn't conforms oracle password definition rules.

and then it's enough to write such a script in your file to connect your schema :

```
#!/bin/bash
# cnn.sh
line '"!p@ssword"'
echo line
sqlplus johnF/$line@127.0.0.1:1521/yourSID
```

and call from prompt :

```
$ . cnn.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem here as well (which really drives me crazy), and this is my answer.

All the special characters allowed in Oracle could be found on this page:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11223_01/doc.910/e11197/app_special_char.htm#MCMAD416

1. If your Oracle password contains any of the special characters on the above page except for a single quotation mark. #o@%+!$(){}[]/^?:`~ for example.

You can use it like this:

```
sh test.sh oracle_user '"#o@%+!$(){}[]/\^?:`~"' ip port service_name
```

2. If your Oracle password contains a single quotation mark. #o@%+!$(){}[]/^?:`~' for example.

You can use it like this:

```
sh test.sh oracle_user '"#o@%+!$(){}[]/\^?:`~'"'"'"' ip port service_name
```

Please be noted that the single quotation mark ' should be replaced with '""'.