# Unable to run oracle query using bash script

Tags: linux, bash, oracle, sh, sqlplus

I have created a script in linux with content-

```
sqlplus -silent test/test123@XYZ <<SQL_QUERY

select * from test.persons;

SQL_QUERY
```

Here-

test - username

test@123 - password

XYZ - SID Name

But wen I am running this I am getting error -

```
ERROR:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified


ERROR:
ORA-12162: TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified


SP2-0306: Invalid option.
```

Can anyone please help me with this issue ?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The error message seems clear: `test/test123@XYZ` is not a correct connection identifier.

Comment: No, not the case @Barmar . It's related to TNS configuration.

Comment: Shell Script with sqlplus and special characters on password
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48491926/shell-script-with-sqlplus-and-special-characters-on-password

Comment: Hey @DmitryDemin , Thank you for your help. One more doubt I am having that how can I store the output of query into some file ?

Comment: "how can I store the output of query into some file ?"  Just like you would anything else from a shell script.  stdout redirection.    'somecommand > myfile.txt' --- That's a gift. You really only get one question per thread.

Comment: Thank you so much @EdStevens for your response. Actually I tried that thing before only but it was not working so I used SPOOF to get the output file.

Comment: If it wasn't working, it's because you had a syntax error, which is easy when you are using sqlplus with a 'here' document (sqlplus ... <<EOF).  But since we don't see your work, we can't know what the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this:

```
test - username
test@123 - password
XYZ - SID Name
```

I am guessing that you actually tried to run:

```
sqlplus -silent test/test@123@XYZ
```

which is why SQL*Plus would have complained because of the 2 "@".

Try putting your password in double quotes to avoid this. An even better way is to put the password in a connection wallet, so its never coded in the script.  See this post for how to do this

https://connor-mcdonald.com/2015/09/21/connection-shortcuts-with-a-wallet/