# Expdp with special character @ password resulting in error

Tags: oracle, passwords, oracle12c, tnsnames

I have set of new boxes where I need to take a copy of export ,
All of this machines have system user password with complex stuff like@ etc..

Ex:

```
expdp system/yada@yada1233*something @hostname:portnumber/servicename
schemas=soso directory=xyz dumpfile=mydump.dmp logfile=mylog.log
```

ERROR:
UDE-12154:opertion generated oracle error 12154
ORA-12154:TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Yeah I know this looks like service name resolution issue but tnsping looks good and is able to resolve I believe this has to do with password having @I have tried putting the password in double quotes adding escape character to special characters etc but none work  any guidance would be great

Also I tried with user that don't have special characters it works fine

edit : As Suggested  here are things I tried and didn't work and still threw the same error

```
expdp system/'yada@yada1233*something' @hostname:portnumber/servicename
schemas=soso directory=xyz dumpfile=mydump.dmp logfile=mylog.log

expdpsystem/"yada@yada1233*something*"@hostname:portnumber/servicename schemas=soso directory=xyz dumpfile=mydump.dmp logfile=mylog.log

expdp system/\"yada@yada1233*something\" @hostname:portnumber/servicename
schemas=soso directory=xyz dumpfile=mydump.dmp logfile=mylog.log

expdp system/"yada\@yada1233\*something" @hostname:portnumber/servicename
schemas=soso directory=xyz dumpfile=mydump.dmp logfile=mylog.log
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48491926/shell-script-with-sqlplus-and-special-characters-on-password/48496798#48496798

Comment: @DmitryDemin The OP states "I have tried putting the password in double quotes". Are you sure that solution works also for `EXPDP`? If you are then vote to close this as a duplicate; if you aren't then a solution for SQL/Plus may not work with `EXPDP`.

Comment: @GBA_Switch Please [edit] your question to show the options you have tried with quotes/escape characters. You say it "doesn't work" but if you've put the quotes in the wrong place then that may be the reason.

Comment: you need to use double quotes and protect the special caracters like that: \@

Comment: Why work yourself into contortions trying to properly escape the problem character?  Just change the password so that is doesn't have an '@' in it.  While you are at it, make sure it also does not have a '$' or a '%', as these can cause problems with the shell processor in *nix or the command processor in Windblows.  And while you are at it, modify the password complexity function to disallow these characters in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SQL> create user "Scott" identified by "T@ger!"
  2  ;

User created.


SQL>  grant connect, resource to "Scott";

Grant succeeded.

SQL>  grant read,write on directory  DATA_PUMP_DIR to "Scott";

Grant succeeded.
```

Example 1

```
more  exp_dp_stroy.sh
 #!/bin/bash

export ORACLE_SID=orastb3
export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1


I=`date +"%d-%m-%y"`
NAMEDUMPFILE=autotest.dmp.$I
PARFILE=/u02/script/parfile_expdp_stroy_autotest
LOG=/u02/script/parfile_expdp_log.log

$ORACLE_HOME/bin/expdp  parfile=$PARFILE  DUMPFILE = $NAMEDUMPFILE  2>$LOG



more /u02/script/parfile_expdp_stroy_autotest
USERID = \"Scott\"/\"T@ger!\"
#    username/password
#SCHEMAS    = "Scott"
DIRECTORY = DATA_PUMP_DIR
CONTENT=ALL
FLASHBACK_TIME=SYSTIMESTAMP


Export: Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production on Fri Oct 1 17:03:32 2021

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
Starting "Scott"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01":  "Scott"/******** parfile=/u02/script/parfile_expdp_stroy_autotest dumpfile=autotest.dmp.01-10-21.
Estimate in progress using BLOCKS method...
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE_DATA
Total estimation using BLOCKS method: 0 KB
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/PRE_SCHEMA/PROCACT_SCHEMA
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/COMMENT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/INDEX
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/CONSTRAINT/CONSTRAINT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/STATISTICS/INDEX_STATISTICS
Master table "Scott"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01" successfully loaded/unloaded
******************************************************************************
Dump file set for Scott.SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01 is:
  /u01/app/oracle/admin/orastb3/dpdump/autotest.dmp.01-10-21
Job "Scott"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01" successfully completed at Fri Oct 1 17:05:05 2021 elapsed 0 00:01:31
```

Example 2

```
more /u02/script/parfile_expdp_stroy_autotest
    USERID = \"Scott\"/\"T@ger!\"@orastb3
    #    username/password
    #SCHEMAS    = "Scott"
    DIRECTORY = DATA_PUMP_DIR
    CONTENT=ALL
    FLASHBACK_TIME=SYSTIMESTAMP

Export: Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production on Fri Oct 1 17:26:21 2021

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
Starting "Scott"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01":  "Scott"/********@orastb3 parfile=/u02/script/parfile_expdp_stroy_autotest dumpfile=autotest.dmp.01-10-21.
Estimate in progress using BLOCKS method...
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE_DATA
Total estimation using BLOCKS method: 0 KB
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/PRE_SCHEMA/PROCACT_SCHEMA
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/COMMENT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/INDEX
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/CONSTRAINT/CONSTRAINT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/STATISTICS/INDEX_STATISTICS
Master table "Scott"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01" successfully loaded/unloaded
******************************************************************************
Dump file set for Scott.SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01 is:
  /u01/app/oracle/admin/orastb3/dpdump/autotest.dmp.01-10-21
Job "Scott"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01" successfully completed at Fri Oct 1 17:26:47 2021 elapsed 0 00:00:25
```

Comment: Thanks for your time because of the time bound activity I have completed the task by granting the USERS(they dont have complex passwords)  necessary privileges  ... but I will try this par file approach  in my future operations and will update here